# Please help me with ScanSnapix1500 install on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu-drivers

Fujitsu does not have a driver for ScanSnap ix1500 for Ubuntu20.04. I was told there is a way to make it work with SANE or xsane. Can anyone please tell me how I can do this and what I need for this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Good to know.  I was thinking about buying this scanner, but I won't if it doesn't have Ubuntu drivers.  Do they happen to have any drivers for similar devices?